# opencart corrupted menu in xampp

Tags: php, xampp, opencart

I copied my files for opencart store from my host and the db to work localy using xampp, but iam experiencing a little problem, the menu in the front end is broken it doesn't look structured.

The links works perfectly fine, i did change the config files to point to the correct folder, rewrite_module is on, changed #RewriteBase / so the links works fine.

I did even update opencart to make sure all files is there, but nothing i have tried is working.

Can someone please help me fix this problem? Have tried everything i can think of.

Iam using Opencart 1.5.6.4

you can see on the following image how the menus look bazaargadgets.com/corrupted menus.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The CSS file isn't being loaded properly (or not at all).

Check to see If it does exist and not corrupted. Re-download anyway just to make sure.

If that doesn't solve your problem, look at the http headers to see exactly what's going on (press F12 in your browser to see dev tools - IE, FF & Chrome)

Comment: The headers are giving following info you can find it on the link, to long to paste here http://bazaargadgets.com/header.txt

Answer (score 0):

you may switch to default theme first,
if working fine, the image link might be broken of your current theme
check the image link